# Let $a \in \Bbb R^n$ and let $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=|x-a|.$ Show that $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $a \in \Bbb R^n$ and let $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ be defined by  $f(x)=|x-a|.$ Show that $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^n$.

So $f$ is continuous at $x_0 \in \Bbb R^n$ if for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there exist an $\delta >0$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \varepsilon$, when $|x-x_0| < \delta.$

Looking at $|f(x)-f(x_0)|$ I get that $$|f(x)-f(x_0)| = ||x-a|-|x_0-a|| \leqslant |(x-a)-(x_0-a)| = |x-x_0|$$

However I'm not sure how I should continue from here to finish the proof. What is my $\delta$?

Comment: You can let it equal $\epsilon$.

Comment: What's happening there? I see that it would work, just feels a bit odd...

Comment: @Daniel ... for all $\epsilon >0$ there exist an $\delta >0$... The $\delta$ that exists here is $\delta = \epsilon$

Comment: Well, you're trying to limit the change in $f$ by limiting the change in $x$. And the ratio $\Delta f/\Delta x$, is roughly $df/dx$. For your function $f \prime$ is $\pm1$, so you can let let $\delta$ be $1 \times\epsilon$. I'm afraid, though, that this is just something that works for this function. To get good as "epsilonics" you just have to see a bunch of examples and grow your bag of tricks.

Comment: you have some great answers here. However, It is a corollary of a more general result: if $\left(X,d\right)$ is a metric space and $p\in X$ so the function $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by $f\left(x\right)=d\left(x,p\right)$ is continous.

Comment: BTW, for other functions you end up with something like $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\leqslant (\text{something ugly})\cdot|x-x_0| $, and your goal becomes to find an upper bound on (something ugly), like $(\text{something ugly}) \lt M$ in a neighborhood of $x$, and then you let $\delta = \epsilon / M$. In your particular problem, (something ugly) isn't ugly, it's just $1$, so your choice of $\delta$ looks very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I see that you have arrived at the following conclusion --
$$ |f(x)-f(x_0)|\leqslant|x-x_0| \:\:\:\text{for all }x,x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n \tag{1}\label{eq}$$

Fix $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$. It remains to prove that given any $\varepsilon >0 $, there is $\delta>0$ such that
$$ |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)| <\varepsilon\:\:\: \text{for all }x \in\mathbb{R}^n$$
Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Choosing $\delta = \varepsilon$ finishes the proof, thanks to $(1)$ above. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

My original answer, shown below, is wrong, since it merely shows (somewhat obtusely)
that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$, rather than showing that 
$f(x)$ is continuous *throughout* $\mathbb{R^n}.$ 
Answer kept rather than deleted as an example of *going off the rails*. 
For the original problem as stated, Alan's answer certainly works.

---

Use the pythagorean theorem.

Intuitively, to start, consider the diagonal of a L x W x H box, 
the **square** of whose length is computed $L^2 + H^2 + W^2.$

Easiest to focus on the **square** of the distance, rather than the
distance itself.

In $R^n$ if $x$ is represented by $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$,

and $a$ is represented by $(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$,

then the square of the distance between $a$ and $x$ is

$D(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n (a_k - x_k)^2.$

If $\delta$ is chosen so that $|x - a| < \delta$, 
then for each $x$ in the region, and each component $x_k$,
$|x_k - a_k| < \delta$.

This means that if $|x - a| < \delta$, then
$D(x) < [n \times (\delta)^2].$

Given $\epsilon > 0$, want to specify $\delta$ such that 
for each $x$ where $|x - a| < \delta$, then $[D(x)] < \epsilon^2.$

This can be done by specifying that $[n \times (\delta)^2] < (\epsilon)^2$

which is done by specifying that $\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}.$